# Объясните , пожалуйста, строку кода

Tags: python, python-3.x

Объясните, пожалуйста, что означает "-" в коде.

```
    sorted(scores, key=lambda k: (-k["score"], k['name'])
```

Comment: Просто изменяет знак числа, наверное

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Не получается отсортировать полученный после применения collections.Counter словари](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1250459/): _Чтобы добиться обратного порядка сортировки значений, предлагается использовать унарный минус `sorted(c.items(), key=lambda item: (-item[1], item[0]))`_

Answer (score 2):

Скорее всего, символ "-" в данном контексте используется для обратной сортировки, таким образом, список будет отсортирован в порядке убывания значения score. И можете прислать полный код